# Positioning z-index does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, html, css

I cannot position `info-pop-title` on top of `bar-header` as you can see from my current code the text "TEST----" is visible but under the `bar-header` element.

http://jsfiddle.net/uvh4ymh9/

Could you point me out what am I doing wrong and how to fix it

PS: I cannot change structure for the HTML, only CSS solution

[image]

---

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <style>
        .bar-header, .bar-footer {
            position: fixed;
            left: 0px;
            width: 1280px;
            z-index: 1;
            background-color: rgba(50,50,50,0.5);
            text-align: center;
        }

        .bar-header {
            top: 0px;
            height: 60px; /* safearea top 25 + content 20 + space bottom 15*/
        }

            .bar-header h1 {
                position: fixed;
                top: 25px; /* safearea top 25 */
                left: 25px; /* safearea left */
                font-size: 20px; /* content */
            }

        .bar-footer {
            top: 670px;
            height: 50px; /* safearea bottom 20 + content 20 + space top 10 */
            font-size: 20px; /* content */
        }

            .bar-footer > ul {
                position: fixed;
                top: 680px; /* footer top 670 + space top 10*/
                left: 1150px;
            }

                .bar-footer > ul li {
                    float: left;
                }

            .bar-footer li:nth-child(1) span {
                color: blue;
            }

        #scene-main {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            width: 1280px;
            height: 720px;
            /*background: #ffffff url("/auth/assets/tv-safearea-transparent.png") no-repeat left;*/
            background-color: darkgrey;
        }

        #btn-up, #btn-down {
            position: fixed;
            left: 1230px;
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: yellow;
            outline: 1px solid black;
            z-index: 200;
        }

        #btn-up {
            top: 0px;
        }

        #btn-down {
            top: 50px;
        }

        #content {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0px; /* header */
        }

        .content-section:first-child {
            margin-top: 60px; /* header height content does not go under header */
        }

        .content-section {
            background-color: lightgray;
            outline: 1px solid black;
            width: 1280px;
        }

        /* Content sizes */
        .content-snippet {
            height: 360px; /* 1 slots */
            width: 1280px;
            background-color: lightblue;
            outline: 1px solid green;
        }

            .content-snippet:nth-child(even) {
                background-color: lightcoral;
            }

        .content-section h2 {
            position: relative;
            top: 30px; /**avoid to go under the header bar*/
        }

        .active {
            background-color: violet !important;
        }

        .snippet-pop-info {
            position: fixed;
            top: 640px; /*430 = final position as visible / 670 = final position as not visible */
            width: 1280px;
            height: 240px;
            background-color: darkblue;
            opacity: 1;
            color: white;
        }

            .snippet-pop-info ul {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0px;
                left: 1155px;
                width: 100px;
            }

                .snippet-pop-info ul li {
                    width: 100px;
                }

            .snippet-pop-info .rating {
                position: absolute;
                top: 65px;
                left: 25px;
                unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
                direction: rtl;
            }

                .snippet-pop-info .rating > span {
                    display: inline-block;
                    position: relative;
                    width: 20px;
                }

                    .snippet-pop-info .rating > span:hover:before,
                    .snippet-pop-info .rating > span:hover ~ span:before {
                        content: "\2605";
                        position: absolute;
                    }

        #info-pop-title {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0px;
            left: 250px;
            z-index: 1;
            font-size: 30px;
            color: white;
            font-weight: bold;
        }


        #info-pop-description {
            position: absolute;
            overflow: hidden; /* hide content that does not fit in the columns*/
            top: 25px;
            left: 300px; /* TEST */
            height: 80px;
            width: 800px;
            font-size: 20px;
            -webkit-column-count: 2;
            -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
            column-count: 2;
            column-gap: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="viewport">


        <div id="scene-main" class="scene" style="">
            <div class="bar-header"><h1>ChannelLive logo</h1></div>
            <div id="page">
                <div id="content">
                    <div id="snippet-cnt-0" class="content-snippet">
                        0
                        <div class="snippet-pop-info" style="top: 720px;">
                            <h1 id="info-pop-title" style="word-wrap: break-word;">TEST-----------------</h1>
                            <div class="rating"><span>☆</span><span>☆</span><span>☆</span><span>☆</span><span>☆</span></div>
                            <div id="info-pop-description" style="word-wrap: break-word;">null</div>
                            <ul>
                                <li class="focusable" data-href="movie-play">Play</li>
                                <li class="focusable" data-href="movie-details">Details</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `#info-pop-title`'s z-index value to 2? Do you mean on-top of as in "covering up" or "appearing before"?

Comment: It's not under it, it's on top. You can tell by setting the header background color to something opaque.

Comment: @j08691 I can't see the header at all in that one; the original looks fine to me. (Well, not "fine" exactly, but it doesn't have the problem claimed in the OP. In Firefox at least.)

Comment: I have added a picture, text TEST should be over the gray bar, TEST should be white on top of gray bar.

Comment: Ah, well it doesn't work in Chrome. The problem looks to me to be that there are too many redundant layers of "position: fixed" elements.

Comment: Correct my problem is in Chrome

Comment: @Pointy which positon:fixed shall I removed? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish, but I can make Chrome work like Firefox by getting rid of the

```
    position: fixed;
```

style from `#content`. Whether that will work in the larger context of your layout, I don't know, but the problem is that the way `z-index` works is weird and complicated, and involves not just individual fixed elements but also any fixed parents they might have.

*edit* — oh also, set the `z-index` of `.snippet-pop-info` to 2.  [Here is an updated version of your fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/y68nLh7x/2/)

Comment: Oops just fixed a typo; it's `#content` not `.content`.

Comment: could you please modify the fiddler, I am not able to make it works following your instruction. Thanks

Comment: @GibboK oops there was something else I changed but didn't notice.

Comment: Thanks for sharing .snippet-pop-info z-index on 2 solved the problem, and it make sense as all content of .snippet-pop-info should be on top of everything else. Once again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Make your

```
.bar-header, .bar-footer{
    z-index:0;
}
```

This will do the trick. Since your z-index for .bar-header and .info-pop-title are the same.

Comment: It won't really do the trick, because one you do that then the whole header disappears completely.

Answer (score 0):

Add z-index in your content div
    #content
    {
        position:fixed;
        top:0;
        z-index:1;
    }

Comment: This also causes the header to disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't make it work with the way your html is nested.
The element you want to pull on top to cover the rest is located in the main container while your second element is isolated in the header. If you want to bring your info-pop-title there you'll have to change the z-index of your #page element, which will cover everything.

The only thing I see you can achieve with this structure would be to position your diverse containers relatively and change the css of your info-pop-title with a negative margin, position absolutely this time.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uvh4ymh9/20/
I correct myself : with a relative wrap, the info-pop-title can stay in fixed positionning it does not matter. The only thing remaining is this "0" in your content which is now 60px from top. If it was wrapped in smething you could either use a negative margin or set it in a fixed position as well.
But, if I can ask, why do you have a so twisted layout...?